# Return only one path of a tree based on a specific criteria

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
 (
  id int,
  parentid int,
  name nvarchar(10)
  )

INSERT customer
VALUES(1,  NULL, 'aaa'),
      (2,  1,    'bbb'),
      (3,  2,    'ccc'),
      (4,  2,    'ddd'),
      (5,  1,    'eee'),
      (6,  5,    'fff'),
      (7,  5,    'ggg'),
      (8,  1,    'hhh'),
      (9,  8,    'iii'),
      (10, 8,    'jjj')
```

I want one path of the branch and not the entire branch for a particular id. For instance, this returns all of the children for a particular id:

```
DECLARE @Id int = your_UnitId
;WITH cte AS 
 (
  SELECT a.Id, a.parentId, a.name
  FROM customer a
  WHERE Id = @Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.Id, a.parentid, a.Name
  FROM customer a JOIN cte c ON a.parentId = c.id
  )
  SELECT parentId, Id, name
  FROM cte
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ad884/7)

I would like, for example to return the rows with 'aaa', 'hhh', 'jjj' when your_UnitId is 1 because that single branch has the highest ids. ('hhh' has the highest id of its siblings, 'jjj' has the highest id of its siblings).

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, you have to delete some customers on your work table to keep only the eldest son. Then you can use your recursive CTE. You can't filter customer inside the recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @Id int = 1

;with biggest_customer as
(
Select Id = max(a.Id), ParentId = a.parentId  
FROM customer a 
group by a.parentId
UNION
Select Id = a.Id, ParentId = a.parentId FROM customer a where a.ID = @ID   
),

biggest_customer_name as
(
select b.*, c.name from biggest_customer b inner join customer c on b.ID=c.ID
),

cte AS 
(
SELECT a.Id, a.parentId, a.name
FROM biggest_customer_name a
WHERE Id = @Id
UNION ALL
SELECT a.Id, a.parentid, a.Name
FROM biggest_customer_name a JOIN cte c ON a.parentId = c.id

)
SELECT parentId, Id, name
FROM cte
```